# Read and get secrete key from PKCS12 file using C#

Tags: c#, pkcs#12

I have PKCS12 file (secured by password) which contains Aux key and main key generated using aux key.
Now I am trying to read the keys programmatically in C#.

Please let me know am I missing something? or the approach I am following is not correct? If so, please share how to achieve it without any third party paid library

I have tried below,

1. Key store explorer
   Using key store explorer, I can read the key using password, but I want to
   do it programmatically.
2. Pkcs12Store (Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs)
   `Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12Store(new FileStream(jksFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), passWord.ToCharArray());`
   Here I am not getting any exception but store returns 0 key count.
3. Using X509Certificate2Collection and X509Certificate2
    `X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection(); collection.Import(jksFilePath, passwordToOpenJKS, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);`
   Here, I collection does not contains any key
4. using X509Certificate2
   `X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(jksFilePath, secString, X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);`
   Here I am getting an error "Parameter incorrect". I have tried all
   possible X509KeyStorageFlags

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("cert_file.pfx", "priv_password");
```

See `PrivateKey` and `HasPrivateKey` members.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried  it but I am getting same error. It return Invalid parameter

Comment: @AmitHadge Are you sure that file is in pfx format and password is correct? You can try to import the certificate from OS to verify parameters. I have worked with this line and it loads certificate successfully.